# How would I add multiple $body_messages?

Tags: php

So I set up a php contact page and this is part of the php that I am having issues with.

```
$body_message ='Application from '.$field_name."\r\n";
$body_message ='Name: ' .$field_name."\r\n";
$body_message ='Email: ' .$field_email."\r\n";
$body_message ='Age: ' .$field_age."\r\n";
$body_message ='Username: ' .$field_usname."\r\n";
$body_message ='Timezone: ' .$field_timezone."\r\n";
$body_message ='Experience: ' .$field_exp."\r\n";
$body_message ='KSP Experience: ' .$field_expksp."\r\n";
$body_message ='Computer Specs: ' .$field_specs."\r\n";
$body_message ='Download Speed: ' .$field_download."\r\n";
$body_message ='Upload Speed: ' .$field_upload."\r\n";
$body_message ='How can they contribute?: ' .$field_contrib."\r\n";
$body_message ='How do they standout?: ' .$field_standout."\r\n";
$body_message ='What is their strengths and weaknesses as a: ' .$field_procon."\r\n";
$body_message ='How can they contribute after the competition?: ' .$field_contribafter."\r\n";
$body_message .='Their schedule: ' .$field_schedule;
```

There is the code the only that shows in the email is the last two items. So how can I fix this problem. Is there to many $body_messages? I wanted to have the "\r\n" for the line breaks. Can someone tell me where I messed up?

Comment: Just like you're doing at the bottom. Concatenate with ".=" everywhere except the first row where you declare the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate all of those strings, you need to have `$body_message .=` for each line *after the first*. You're currently setting `$body_message` to the second to last string, then concatenating it with the last.

See [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Example :

$messagework = "Name : ".$name;

$messagework .= ". School : ".$school;

$messagework .= ". Address : ".$address;

$messagework .= ". Email : ".$email;

$messagework .= ". Tel : ".$phone;

You can looking for on [free php script email](http://www.code4share.net/category/php/email/)